# Finding software development contracts

Tags: contracts

For the last few years I've been working as a self-employed software developer. Doing various gigs as they came my way. For the most part I've been fairly lucky, as my own personal network has yielded all the work I need to sustain myself and then some. As I said, I've been *lucky* to get all my contracts, I haven't had to put any real effort into finding work yet.

Although I'm currently employed, I'm unhappy and thinking about moving on.

My question is for the experienced self-employed contractors, how did you find your contracts? Are recruiters/headhunters/agencies helpful? What is the best way to expand your professional network? Can the internet be useful?

Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Craigslist, network with former co-workers. Stay away from [rent-a-slave](http://www.rentacoder.com/) and [elame](http://elance.com) sites. They will only waste your time and frustrate you (I want a youtube/facebook/amazon clone for under $500).

Local is better. Clients love to have you come onsite and talk with them.

It will take a bit but after a while, you will find enough clients who keep you busy and you won't have time to look for new ones :D.

Start off moonlighting so you can keep the lights on and the internet paid while this ramp up happens.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh yeah, don't buy into to much BS you will hear. They will think their product is the best thing since gravy. Remember cash is king, and you are the handmaiden.

Comment: I've always been amazed by rent-a-slave. you see listings like "Require complete website for company, including full e-commerce etc etc. Maximum bid $120"

Comment: That's because people think this sort of stuff is simple. I have a friend that wanted me to work on a project, I said no, I didn't have time, and they were like, "That's fine, I want to learn to code anyway". "Ok, are you going to put a multi-year commitment into it?"